# Как выключить Jack Compiler Android

Tags: android

Как выключить Jack Compiler Android?

Answer (score 1):

Он по умолчанию не включен. Включается обычно строчкой в build.gradle файле. Соответственно если удалить эту строчку, то отключите Jack